# NSView 'window' is deprecated XCode 4

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have installed lately XCode 4+, and since on I get warning message 'window' is deprecated. 
I have subclassed NSView and called it CentralView and used it to load various views dynamically. I had to subclass the NSView, because there are methods I needed to override.
In other class that controls loading central views I have created following method:

```
- (IBAction)showUserInfoView:(id)sender{
   NSLog(@"Load new user info page");
   // Try to end editing
   NSWindow *w = [centralView window]; // Here I get warning 'window' is deprecated
   BOOL ended = [w makeFirstResponder:w];
   if (!ended) {
       NSBeep();
       return;
   }
   // Put the view in the box
   NSView *v = [[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view];
   NSArray* viewSet = [NSArray arrayWithObject: v];
   [centralView setSubviews: viewSet];
```

}

As far as I am aware the window method in NSView is up to date. Why do I get message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `centralView`? What happens if you say `[(NSView*)centralView window]`?

It's possible that the compiler is not finding `-[NSView window]`, but some other `-window` method which is deprecated. If `centralView` is declared as an `id` then the compiler doesn't know it's an `NSView` and has to guess.

Comment: This; -[NSView window] is definitely not deprecated.

Comment: Casting centralView resolves the problem, but I really don't see the reason why should I do it. There is only one centralView instance of NSView subclass and there are no other methods called "window" involved anywhere else. I would never create myself a method that is called "window" by the way.

Comment: BTW centralView is not declared as an 'id'. It is declared as CentralView subclass of NSView

Comment: In this .m file, did you import the header where CentralView is defined? You might have forward-declared it (`@class CentralView;`) which would have similar effects -- the compiler knows it's a class but doesn't know exactly which one.

Comment: Such a silly error. I have declared class in header file (@class CentralView;) but didn't import actual file in .m file. Thanks for help.